Is it possible to pause a python script that has already started running and check the value of a variable?
Even though the title is self explanatory, I have a python script running for quite a few days and I want to know if there is a way to pause it and check the value of a variable.
If I haven't already written code in the script for that purpose before running it, is it possible to check the value of this variable now?

Maybe you'll succeed to attach a debugger to the running process (e.g. via PyCharm), but the chance is low

@AlexeyS.Larionov That's possible with process-level debuggers like gdb, but I doubt it can be done with debuggers for interpreted languages like Python.

What research have you done? There are existing questions like this for example: Is it possible to attach a console into a running Python process?

you can use a debugger to attach to the running process. I think this can be done via pdb-attach.
Step 1: Identify the pid of your running script (You can use ps aux on linux ie)
ps aux|grep python
Step 2: Attach to the process using pdb-attach with the PID you found:
pdb-attach <PID>
Step 3: At the pdb prompt you can run various things to inspect:
(Pdb) p variable_name
(Pdb) l --> current line
(Pdb) c --> continue


What's pdb-attach? It's not part of pdb.

https://pypi.org/project/pdb-attach/

Two things you should mention from the docs: "Unfortunately pdb-attach doesn't work on Windows." and "pdb_attach must be imported and set up in the python program of interest in order for a user to attach to the running program."
